# Decorating Shopware6 api controller for saves pluginreader data to entity

Tags: php, shopware

After installing the plugin and editing the available fields in the configuration, I would like to save these fields to my entity.

so I created the Config class to make the field getter from the plugin configuration like:

```
class Config
{
    public const SYSTEM_CONFIG_DOMAIN = 'myEntity.config.';

    /** @var SystemConfigService $systemConfigService */
    protected static $systemConfigService;

    public function __construct(SystemConfigService $systemConfigService)
    {
        self::$systemConfigService = $systemConfigService;
    }
}

public static function message(): string
{
    return (string)self::$systemConfigService->get(self::SYSTEM_CONFIG_DOMAIN . 'message');
}
```

I found such a controller in platforms:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/v{version}/_action/system-config/batch", name="api.action.core.save.system-config.batch", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function batchSaveConfiguration(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    foreach ($request->request->all() as $salesChannelId => $kvs) {
        if ($salesChannelId === 'null') {
            $salesChannelId = null;
        }
        $this->saveKeyValues($salesChannelId, $kvs);
    }

    //save to my entity here
    return new JsonResponse([$request->request->all()]);
}
```

And in this controller I would like to add my message from pluginConfig to my entity.
Is this a good idea and how can I thank it? Could I ask for more code than usual because I'm just learning sw6?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add data to your plugin configuration you should use a config installer instead of a controller.